# How to use nodejs to find out file rename event?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to use nodejs to find out file rename event?

Node provide `fs.watch` API to listen file change/create/delete event, but we can not listen rename/move event

Answer (score 2):

If you watch a directory, you'll (probably) get `rename` events for things within it getting renamed. In fact, you'll get two: One listing the old name, another listing the new name. (Yes, this is less than ideal.)

```
const fs = require("fs");
const watcher = fs.watch("the-directory", {recursive: true}, (eventType, fileName) => {
    if (eventType === "rename") {
        console.log(`${fileName} was renamed`);
    }
});
```

If you rename the file `foo` to `bar` in the directory, you'll see:

```
foo was renamed
bar was renamed
```

That's assuming `fs.watch` works in your environment, there are [lots of caveats in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener).